# How do you have a bullet in a bullet list have it's own independent alternate glyps than the paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign

[image]

I want to have my bullet be the 'fancy' alternate Q glyph, but the bullet text have the regular capital glyphs like on the right. Everytime I change the first letter glyph it changes the bullet glyph back to the regular or alternate glyph.

Comment: Are you using actual bullets, or is it plain text? Are you using a paragraph style for the list? Is the fancy alternate Q glyph available through swash alternates or perhaps through a stylistic set, or do you have to input it manually? If you’re using a bullet list and the swash Q is available as an alternate, you should be able to set up a character style with the appropriate swash alternates turned on, and then in your bullet list paragraph style set the bullet to use that character style. Have you tried that already?

Comment: It was actual bullets, with a paragraph style for the bullet text, it was available through swash alternates and I was able to use a character style to define the bullet as the swash alternates. Thanks for the help! I can post further screenshots to anyone who comes across this and needs explanation like I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using swash alternates on a character style, and then nesting that character style onto your bullet, you will be able to have the bullet be the alternate glyph, but the rest of the bullet text not have the alternate glyphs

[image]

[image]